# Splitting up data in the form "xxx-yyyy people" into two variables php

Tags: php

Given that I have a variable $peopleSize in the format (I've already extracted the information from the UI element):

```
xxx-yyyy people
```

For example as seen in the jquery range UI:

http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/SLvtx/1/

How would I get the two min and max as two seperate variables using PHP getting rid of the "-" and "people"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many ways to do it: [split the string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) on `'-'` and `' '`.

```
$peopleSize = 'xxx-yyyy people';
$parts = preg_split('-| ', $peopleSize);
$min = $parts[0];
$max = $parts[1];
```

Comment: I'm sure there are more idiomatic ways to do this, however.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way is to use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/sscanf) like

```
sscanf("3-456 people", "%d-%d", $min, $max);
// $min contains 3, $max contains 456
```

Comment: Not just one liner; one function. Mine's also one line but contains three functions. salathe wins. ;)

Comment: Looks to me like MДΓΓ БДLL "wins", but thanks for the comments. It continually surprises me how few people know/use these simple string functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
list($min, $max) = explode('-', strtok($peopleSize, ' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = "300-1000 people";

preg_match("|(\d+)-(\d+)|", $str, $matches);

//$matches[0] will hold the whole min-max string.

$min = $matches[1]; //First matched group, first set of numbers.
$max = $matches[2]; //Second matched group, second set of numbers.

echo "$min to $max";
```